# .net Core Many to Many relationship

Tags: optimization, asp.net-core, orm, entity-framework-core

I am trying to determine what would be the smartest way to accomplish this.  I may be way way overthinking what I am trying to do, but here goes.

I have the following entities, simplified

```
public class Meet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //various properties
    public List<MeetComp> Competitors { get; set; }
}

public class Competitor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // various properties
    public List<MeetComp> Meets { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GymManager")]
    public int GymManagerId { get; set; }
    public GymManager GymManager { get; set; }
}

public class GymManager
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //various properties
    public List<Competitor> Competitors { get; set; }
}

public class MeetComp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Competitor")]
    public int CompetitorId { get; set; }
    public Competitor Competitor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Meet")]
    public int MeetId { get; set; }
    public Meet Meet { get; set; }
}
```

So I am creating a razor page where I get a specific Gymmanager and load all the related competitors to display in a list, which I have working just fine.

However I need another list (on the same page) of the related competitors of the Gymmanager but also who have an entry in the "MeetComp" table by a specific meetid.  So List #1 is all of my Competitors and List #2 is all of my Comptetitors that are registered for that Meet.

Would it be smarter to have EF pull the data I get the data the first time with a ThenInclude()? Then I write some logic to determine if they get added to list #2? or should I make another trip to the Database?  Then if I do make another trip to the database is there an easy to way to query for the List of CompId's I already have?

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I ended up doing is making another trip to the DB.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetRegisteredComps(List<int> Comps, int meetid)
    {
        if(Comps.Count == 0)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        if(meetid == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var query = _context.MeetsComps.Include(c => c.Competitor)
            .AsQueryable();
        query = query.Where(c => c.MeetId == meetid);
        query = query.Where(c => Comps.Contains(c.CompetitorId));

        var results = await query.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(results);
    }
```

Comment: you don't have to reuse the query separately for each where. you cn do it directly with `&&`

Comment: `_context.MeetsComps.Include(c => c.Competitor).Where(c => c.MeetId == meetid && Comps.Contains(c.CompetitorId))`